# Concat Dynamic Variables with static URLs

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, hyperlink, website-integration

I have URLs that are dynamic based on the user I want e.g. `https://website.com/user/username/settings` . The data extension I want to `set @username = username`, then input it in the middle of the string and concat the three values. This is the AMPscript I have below, but *I keep running into a 404 error where it's not picking up the username* and just defaulting them to `https://website.com/user/settings`. Any thoughts?

AMPscript below:

```ampscript
%%[ 
Var @URL, @Username, @UserURL
Set @URL = "https://website.com/user/" 
Set @Username= @Username
Set @UserURL = Concat(@URL,@username, "/settings") 
]%%

<!-- Email Code -->

<a href="%%=RedirectTo(@UserURL)=%%"> Go to your username page </a>
```

Comment: is this a type in your code Set @Username= @Username. should it be Set @Username= Username

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest sending the email to yourself, copying the URL from the email into  [wheregoes.com](https://wheregoes.com) to investigate the tracking hop and then the final destination URL.

You should always test links from your inbox, not send-preview.